# 404 Not Found: Deploying PHP app on Heroku

Tags: php, heroku

I'm trying to deploy a PHP app on Heroku but i've ran into an issue. My project structure is as such:

```
+main 
 +app
   +view (contains all my pages) 
 +public_html 
   + assets (contains css/js files) 
   -index.php 
-Procfile 
-composer.json
-.htaccess
```

**index.php**

```
<?php
// Grabs the URI and breaks it apart in case we have querystring stuff
$request_uri = explode('?', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 2);

$routes = array(
    "/" => "home",
    "/contact" => "contact",
    "/crew-search" => "crew-search",
    "/dashboard" => "dashboard",
    "/documentation" => "documentation",
    "/entry-list" => "entry-list",
    "/gallery" => "gallery",
    "/links" => "links",
    "/login" => "login",
    "/media" => "media",
    "/results" => "results",
    "/schedule" => "schedule",
    "/sponsors" => "sponsors"
);

if(isset($routes[$request_uri[0]])) {
  require '../app/view/'.$routes[$request_uri[0]].'.php';
} else {
  header('HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found');
  require '../app/view/404.php';
}
```

**Procfile**

```
web: vendor/bin/heroku-php-apache2 public_html/
```

**.htaccess**

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

**Error message when trying to access all pages. Strangely, this works fine on localhost. For example:**

```
The requested URL /documentation was not found on this server.
```

Thank you.

Comment: You don't have a .Htaccess?

Comment: The other routes work on heroku?

Comment: Nope, all the routes don't work. @simon.ro

Comment: Does it work on your development machine? I'm confused as to why your htaccess is within the root but index is within public_html yet there's no rewrite to push into public_html?

Comment: Sorry, have just read that it works locally, although I'm going to hazard a guess that you've setup a hosts file locally which treats public_html as document root?

Comment: I read your comment and realized my .htaccess was in the wrong folder. It works fine now. Thanks a million! @Doug

Comment: Added as an answer, if you would be so kind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your htaccess file is in the wrong place, try moving it to public_html and it will work.